# read file descriptor HANGS

Tags: c++, c, filesystems, system

I have a very simple source reading file descriptor which **hangs**. 
Could anyone notice the problem the code has?

The first one is the problematic source and the second one is the working source found on the web. Two sources are almost identical.

- First source

  ```
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <sys/stat.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <fcntl.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
       int n, in;
       char buf[1024];

      if ((in = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)<0)) {
          perror(argv[1]);
          return -1;
      }

      while((n = read(in, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0 ) { //HANGS at THIS LINE!!!!!!!!!!!
          printf("TEST\n");
      }

      close(in);

      return 0;
  }
  ```
- Second Working source got from online

  ```
  /*
   * ============================================================================
   *  Name        : sp_linux_copy.c
   *  Author      : Marko Martinović
   *  Description : Copy input file into output file
   *  ============================================================================
   **/

  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <fcntl.h>
  #include <errno.h>
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <unistd.h>

  #define BUF_SIZE 8192

  int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

      int input_fd;    /* Input and output file descriptors */
      ssize_t ret_in;    /* Number of bytes returned by read() and write() */
      char buffer[BUF_SIZE];      /* Character buffer */

      /* Create input file descriptor */
      input_fd = open (argv [1], O_RDONLY);
      if (input_fd == -1) {
          perror ("open");
          return 2;
      }

      /* Copy process */
      while((ret_in = read (input_fd, &buffer, BUF_SIZE)) > 0){
          printf("TEST\n");
      }

      /* Close file descriptors */
      close (input_fd);
  }
  ```

Comment: Exactly what do you do to test this?

Comment: I implemented copying files which needs read and write. To clarify my problem and easier to see for reviewers, I removed write code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By a funny coincidence, you are reading from `stdin`. This is because in your `if(in = ...` you misplaced some brackets.

What is happening is that first `open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)<0` gets evaluated, and the result gets put into `in`. Since the result of `open()` is not smaller than zero (on succesfull open), `in` becomes 0. And `stdin` is the name for the filedescriptor which is zero (on most systems). So it is a valid file descriptor, and read is very happy to read from it. It is just not getting any, until you type something in your console.

quick fix:

```
if ( (in = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
```

Comment: Another 'clever code' compound expression goes wrong:(  Since splitting up the line would have revealed/fixed the bug,  I'm upvoting you for spotting the error and downvoting OP question as yet another depressing failure to debug:(

Comment: Im not sure that is reason to downvote, it is definitely a learning experience though, and maybe i should have mentioned this in my answer.

Comment: Ah. Silly mistake. I was working this code for almost two hours before asking the question. Thanks @David van rijn